# reading only the second row of an xlsx file using roo

Tags: ruby, roo

I am using `roo` to read an xlsx file.

```
book = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("codes.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet('Sheet1')
```

This reads all the rows in the file.

I can iterate through this sheet using

```
plans_sheet.each(column_1: 'column_1', column_2: 'column_2') do |hash|
```

But this iteration happens from the first row which has all the column names as well.
I need to take **only** the second row data.

Update -
when you do row(2) it returns you an array. And when you are iterating using .each it returns you a hash which has column names as your key .

How to do that.

Comment: Did you try `plans_sheet.row(2)`?

Comment: Next time before you ask online, please try to research the question yourself ;-) . I don't know Roo, I literally just google Roo Gem and found the answer after scrolling for 5 seconds in the Readme.

Comment: @themaster Sorry I assumed you had not checked. So you want ALL the rows, excluding the first row? Your question ist still not very clear on that: You want only the second row? Or all the data except the first row?

Comment: I want only the second row as a hash.

Answer (score 2):

`Roo::Excelx#each` method returns standard Ruby Enumerator:

```
enum = sheet.each(column_1: 'column_1', column_2: 'column_2')
enum.class # => Enumerator
```

So there are two ways to achieve your goal:

1) Use `drop` method:

```
enum.drop(1).each do |hash| 
  # do something with the hash    
end
```

If you need only the second row:

```
  hash = enum.drop(1).first
```

2) Move the internal position of the iterator:

```
enum.next # move 1 step forward to skip the first row

# continue moving
loop do
  hash = enum.next
  # do something with the hash
end
```

If you need only the second row:

```
  enum.next # skip the first row
  hash = enum.next # second row
```

**Also take into account:**

There is`Roo::Excelx::Sheet` class which also represents a worksheet and has the `each_row` method that receives `:offset` parameter. But unfortunately it doesn't have an option to transform a row into a hash with given keys.

```
book = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("codes.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_for('Sheet1')

sheet.each_row(offset: 1) do |row| # skip first row
  # do something with the row
end
```

Comment: Updated the answer about how to get only the second row

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over rows starting from the second one, just use [Enumerable#drop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop)

```
plans_sheet.each(column_1: 'column_1', column_2: 'column_2').drop(1) do |hash|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
whatever_sheet.row(2)
```

It is always good to have a look at the documentation, it is explained in the README.md of the Gem, see https://github.com/roo-rb/roo#accessing-rows-and-columns

Comment: I did check .. when you do row(2) it returns you an array. And when you are iterating using .each it returns you a hash which has column names as your key .I hope this clears my doubts somewhat